# How to write a bash script using Mac to take files with the same date and put them in a folder with that date

Tags: bash, macos

I have hundreds of datalogger files in a directory and I want to write a bash script that will take files with the same date in the filename (an example file name is "2016-06-15T170000_SMARTFLUX.data", where 2016-06-15 is the date) and store them in a folder with the date as the name. I am using a Mac Terminal window, which I believe is Linux (I apologize for my ignorance in computer terminology)

So far I have:

```
#Type of file (extension) to process:
FILES=*.data

#get date string from file name to use for newly created file
DATE=`ls $FILES|head -n 1|cut -c 1-10`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have only modified a bash script that combines these types of files into a text, and I have not created any folders or moved files.

Comment: FYI, mac is not Linux; it's based on FreeBSD.  That said, bash is bash on any of the *nix platform.

Comment: DId you google at all?  https://www.google.com/search?q=move+files+with+date+stamp+to+directory+bash+site:stackoverflow.com gets me some 3,000 hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your script is in the same dir as the data files:

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.data; do
    target_dir=${filename:0:10}
    if [[ ! -d $target_dir ]]; then
        mkdir $target_dir
    fi
    mv $filename $target_dir
done
```